# Visual Studios : counter- controlled loops

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

wondering if anyone could help me get my code to work. I have to use a counter-controlled loop in my visual studios program, but i'm not entirely sure how it even works. I know that its used to perform a certain number of times, but thats about it.

So what i have to do is have a counter for "States" where each time someone enters a state into a ListBox, the counter label goes up. because there is only 50 states, im guessing thats how many times the loop should go through
this is what i have:

```
Dim statecounter As Integer = 0
Do While statecounter < 51
statecounter += 1
Loop
```

problem is the label goes right to 51 with one click.
any solutions?? thank you for any help

Comment: If you want it to increment when  `someone enters a state`, you dont need a loop.  Increment it when they enter the name/data.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: thats what i thought as well, but my assignment literally says : "each time a user adds a state a couner should show the current number of states, this should be done via counter controlled loop" which is why im so confused